# Full disc encryption with GRUB2

Tags: linux, encryption, grub2

Does anyone know of a good Howto on how to fully encrypt a HDD (even the /boot!) with GRUB2?

Is it possible using fedora 14 or ubuntu 10.04?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the link:
http://xercestech.com/full-system-encryption-for-linux.geek

Comment: [Please don't just post a link as an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259), both because the linked site may be unavailable, and because as it is your answer doesn't show what it's about. Summarize the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @Gilles, well, that's discussion, not final resolution -- copying huge amount of text with losing formatting does not make any sense for me (not even mentioning traffic stealing -- images -- which is forbidden on **all** sites, because of technical issues, not good manners). Linking is valid mechanism in Internet, and copying Internet "just in case" is somewhat redundant. In short, no-go.

Comment: *Summarize*, not copy. An answer with just a link is not useful (and trigger-happy viewers have been known to flag such answers as spam).